# All Microsoft Standard Colors In Hex

Tags: visual-studio, colors, hex, color-picker

Recently I've been converting a Visual Studio (C#) Project to the web.
One of the features involved the ability to select from the MS Standard palette.

So I need a list of the MS Standard Colors in Hex.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. It would be more helpful to the community if you would change your question to an actual question and post your solution as an answer. Then you can accept your answer.

Comment: You can reference the MS Standard Colors via CSS by using their name. `background-color: aliceblue;`

Comment: @MattRazza - Browser support and consistency aren't a guarantee when using the X11 names (some color clashes can occur, for example):

http://sixrevisions.com/css/colors-webdesign/

You know where you are using Hex.

Comment: @Richard Correct but all modern, major browsers conform to the [spec](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colornames.asp).

Comment: It gets worse @MattRazza, I've found other premade lists of the colors too :( Oh well - at least the method is visible. Should anyone else want to waste their time!

Comment: I've also added a slightly darker version of each colour used as a border underneath my original answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After searching I couldn't find a list of these ARGB colours in hex so I wrote a bit of JS to convert them for me.

I figure I can't be the only person who needs these, so here you go!

> AliceBlue     #F0F8FF
>
> AntiqueWhite  #FAEBD7
>
> Aqua  #00FFFF
>
> Aquamarine    #7FFFD4
>
> Azure     #F0FFFF
>
> Beige     #F5F5DC
>
> Bisque    #FFE4C4
>
> Black     #000000
>
> BlanchedAlmond    #FFEBCD
>
> Blue  #0000FF
>
> BlueViolet    #8A2BE2
>
> Brown     #A52A2A
>
> BurlyWood     #DEB887
>
> CadetBlue     #5F9EA0
>
> Chartreuse    #7FFF00
>
> Chocolate     #D2691E
>
> Coral     #FF7F50
>
> CornflowerBlue    #6495ED
>
> Cornsilk  #FFF8DC
>
> Crimson   #DC143C
>
> Cyan  #00FFFF
>
> DarkBlue  #00008B
>
> DarkCyan  #008B8B
>
> DarkGoldenrod     #B8860B
>
> DarkGray  #A9A9A9
>
> DarkGreen     #006400
>
> DarkKhaki     #BDB76B
>
> DarkMagenta   #8B008B
>
> DarkOliveGreen    #556B2F
>
> DarkOrange    #FF8C00
>
> DarkOrchid    #9932CC
>
> DarkRed   #8B0000
>
> DarkSalmon    #E9967A
>
> DarkSeaGreen  #8FBC8F
>
> DarkSlateBlue     #483D8B
>
> DarkSlateGray     #2F4F4F
>
> DarkTurquoise     #00CED1
>
> DarkViolet    #9400D3
>
> DeepPink  #FF1493
>
> DeepSkyBlue   #00BFFF
>
> DimGray   #696969
>
> DodgerBlue    #1E90FF
>
> Firebrick     #B22222
>
> FloralWhite   #FFFAF0
>
> ForestGreen   #228B22
>
> Fuchsia   #FF00FF
>
> Gainsboro     #DCDCDC
>
> GhostWhite    #F8F8FF
>
> Gold  #FFD700
>
> Goldenrod     #DAA520
>
> Gray  #808080
>
> Green     #008000
>
> GreenYellow   #ADFF2F
>
> Honeydew  #F0FFF0
>
> HotPink   #FF69B4
>
> IndianRed     #CD5C5C
>
> Indigo    #4B0082
>
> Ivory     #FFFFF0
>
> Khaki     #F0E68C
>
> Lavender  #E6E6FA
>
> LavenderBlush     #FFF0F5
>
> LawnGreen     #7CFC00
>
> LemonChiffon  #FFFACD
>
> LightBlue     #ADD8E6
>
> LightCoral    #F08080
>
> LightCyan     #E0FFFF
>
> LightGoldenrodYellow  #FAFAD2
>
> LightGray     #D3D3D3
>
> LightGreen    #90EE90
>
> LightPink     #FFB6C1
>
> LightSalmon   #FFA07A
>
> LightSeaGreen     #20B2AA
>
> LightSkyBlue  #87CEFA
>
> LightSlateGray    #778899
>
> LightSteelBlue    #B0C4DE
>
> LightYellow   #FFFFE0
>
> Lime  #00FF00
>
> LimeGreen     #32CD32
>
> Linen     #FAF0E6
>
> Magenta   #FF00FF
>
> Maroon    #800000
>
> MediumAquamarine  #66CDAA
>
> MediumBlue    #0000CD
>
> MediumOrchid  #BA55D3
>
> MediumPurple  #9370DB
>
> MediumSeaGreen    #3CB371
>
> MediumSlateBlue   #7B68EE
>
> MediumSpringGreen     #00FA9A
>
> MediumTurquoise   #48D1CC
>
> MediumVioletRed   #C71585
>
> MidnightBlue  #191970
>
> MintCream     #F5FFFA
>
> MistyRose     #FFE4E1
>
> Moccasin  #FFE4B5
>
> NavajoWhite   #FFDEAD
>
> Navy  #000080
>
> OldLace   #FDF5E6
>
> Olive     #808000
>
> OliveDrab     #6B8E23
>
> Orange    #FFA500
>
> OrangeRed     #FF4500
>
> Orchid    #DA70D6
>
> PaleGoldenrod     #EEE8AA
>
> PaleGreen     #98FB98
>
> PaleTurquoise     #AFEEEE
>
> PaleVioletRed     #DB7093
>
> PapayaWhip    #FFEFD5
>
> PeachPuff     #FFDAB9
>
> Peru  #CD853F
>
> Pink  #FFC0CB
>
> Plum  #DDA0DD
>
> PowderBlue    #B0E0E6
>
> Purple    #800080
>
> Red   #FF0000
>
> RosyBrown     #BC8F8F
>
> RoyalBlue     #4169E1
>
> SaddleBrown   #8B4513
>
> Salmon    #FA8072
>
> SandyBrown    #F4A460
>
> SeaGreen  #2E8B57
>
> SeaShell  #FFF5EE
>
> Sienna    #A0522D
>
> Silver    #C0C0C0
>
> SkyBlue   #87CEEB
>
> SlateBlue     #6A5ACD
>
> SlateGray     #708090
>
> Snow  #FFFAFA
>
> SpringGreen   #00FF7F
>
> SteelBlue     #4682B4
>
> Tan   #D2B48C
>
> Teal  #008080
>
> Thistle   #D8BFD8
>
> Tomato    #FF6347
>
> Transparent   none
>
> Turquoise     #40E0D0
>
> Violet    #EE82EE
>
> Wheat     #F5DEB3
>
> White     #FFFFFF
>
> WhiteSmoke    #F5F5F5
>
> Yellow    #FFFF00
>
> YellowGreen   #9ACD32

Or as a block of CSS Classes:

```
.AliceBlue{background-color:#F0F8FF;}
.AntiqueWhite{background-color:#FAEBD7;}
.Aqua{background-color:#00FFFF;}
.Aquamarine{background-color:#7FFFD4;}
.Azure{background-color:#F0FFFF;}
.Beige{background-color:#F5F5DC;}
.Bisque{background-color:#FFE4C4;}
.Black{background-color:#000000;}
.BlanchedAlmond{background-color:#FFEBCD;}
.Blue{background-color:#0000FF;}
.BlueViolet{background-color:#8A2BE2;}
.Brown{background-color:#A52A2A;}
.BurlyWood{background-color:#DEB887;}
.CadetBlue{background-color:#5F9EA0;}
.Chartreuse{background-color:#7FFF00;}
.Chocolate{background-color:#D2691E;}
.Coral{background-color:#FF7F50;}
.CornflowerBlue{background-color:#6495ED;}
.Cornsilk{background-color:#FFF8DC;}
.Crimson{background-color:#DC143C;}
.Cyan{background-color:#00FFFF;}
.DarkBlue{background-color:#00008B;}
.DarkCyan{background-color:#008B8B;}
.DarkGoldenrod{background-color:#B8860B;}
.DarkGray{background-color:#A9A9A9;}
.DarkGreen{background-color:#006400;}
.DarkKhaki{background-color:#BDB76B;}
.DarkMagenta{background-color:#8B008B;}
.DarkOliveGreen{background-color:#556B2F;}
.DarkOrange{background-color:#FF8C00;}
.DarkOrchid{background-color:#9932CC;}
.DarkRed{background-color:#8B0000;}
.DarkSalmon{background-color:#E9967A;}
.DarkSeaGreen{background-color:#8FBC8F;}
.DarkSlateBlue{background-color:#483D8B;}
.DarkSlateGray{background-color:#2F4F4F;}
.DarkTurquoise{background-color:#00CED1;}
.DarkViolet{background-color:#9400D3;}
.DeepPink{background-color:#FF1493;}
.DeepSkyBlue{background-color:#00BFFF;}
.DimGray{background-color:#696969;}
.DodgerBlue{background-color:#1E90FF;}
.Firebrick{background-color:#B22222;}
.FloralWhite{background-color:#FFFAF0;}
.ForestGreen{background-color:#228B22;}
.Fuchsia{background-color:#FF00FF;}
.Gainsboro{background-color:#DCDCDC;}
.GhostWhite{background-color:#F8F8FF;}
.Gold{background-color:#FFD700;}
.Goldenrod{background-color:#DAA520;}
.Gray{background-color:#808080;}
.Green{background-color:#008000;}
.GreenYellow{background-color:#ADFF2F;}
.Honeydew{background-color:#F0FFF0;}
.HotPink{background-color:#FF69B4;}
.IndianRed{background-color:#CD5C5C;}
.Indigo{background-color:#4B0082;}
.Ivory{background-color:#FFFFF0;}
.Khaki{background-color:#F0E68C;}
.Lavender{background-color:#E6E6FA;}
.LavenderBlush{background-color:#FFF0F5;}
.LawnGreen{background-color:#7CFC00;}
.LemonChiffon{background-color:#FFFACD;}
.LightBlue{background-color:#ADD8E6;}
.LightCoral{background-color:#F08080;}
.LightCyan{background-color:#E0FFFF;}
.LightGoldenrodYellow{background-color:#FAFAD2;}
.LightGray{background-color:#D3D3D3;}
.LightGreen{background-color:#90EE90;}
.LightPink{background-color:#FFB6C1;}
.LightSalmon{background-color:#FFA07A;}
.LightSeaGreen{background-color:#20B2AA;}
.LightSkyBlue{background-color:#87CEFA;}
.LightSlateGray{background-color:#778899;}
.LightSteelBlue{background-color:#B0C4DE;}
.LightYellow{background-color:#FFFFE0;}
.Lime{background-color:#00FF00;}
.LimeGreen{background-color:#32CD32;}
.Linen{background-color:#FAF0E6;}
.Magenta{background-color:#FF00FF;}
.Maroon{background-color:#800000;}
.MediumAquamarine{background-color:#66CDAA;}
.MediumBlue{background-color:#0000CD;}
.MediumOrchid{background-color:#BA55D3;}
.MediumPurple{background-color:#9370DB;}
.MediumSeaGreen{background-color:#3CB371;}
.MediumSlateBlue{background-color:#7B68EE;}
.MediumSpringGreen{background-color:#00FA9A;}
.MediumTurquoise{background-color:#48D1CC;}
.MediumVioletRed{background-color:#C71585;}
.MidnightBlue{background-color:#191970;}
.MintCream{background-color:#F5FFFA;}
.MistyRose{background-color:#FFE4E1;}
.Moccasin{background-color:#FFE4B5;}
.NavajoWhite{background-color:#FFDEAD;}
.Navy{background-color:#000080;}
.OldLace{background-color:#FDF5E6;}
.Olive{background-color:#808000;}
.OliveDrab{background-color:#6B8E23;}
.Orange{background-color:#FFA500;}
.OrangeRed{background-color:#FF4500;}
.Orchid{background-color:#DA70D6;}
.PaleGoldenrod{background-color:#EEE8AA;}
.PaleGreen{background-color:#98FB98;}
.PaleTurquoise{background-color:#AFEEEE;}
.PaleVioletRed{background-color:#DB7093;}
.PapayaWhip{background-color:#FFEFD5;}
.PeachPuff{background-color:#FFDAB9;}
.Peru{background-color:#CD853F;}
.Pink{background-color:#FFC0CB;}
.Plum{background-color:#DDA0DD;}
.PowderBlue{background-color:#B0E0E6;}
.Purple{background-color:#800080;}
.Red{background-color:#FF0000;}
.RosyBrown{background-color:#BC8F8F;}
.RoyalBlue{background-color:#4169E1;}
.SaddleBrown{background-color:#8B4513;}
.Salmon{background-color:#FA8072;}
.SandyBrown{background-color:#F4A460;}
.SeaGreen{background-color:#2E8B57;}
.SeaShell{background-color:#FFF5EE;}
.Sienna{background-color:#A0522D;}
.Silver{background-color:#C0C0C0;}
.SkyBlue{background-color:#87CEEB;}
.SlateBlue{background-color:#6A5ACD;}
.SlateGray{background-color:#708090;}
.Snow{background-color:#FFFAFA;}
.SpringGreen{background-color:#00FF7F;}
.SteelBlue{background-color:#4682B4;}
.Tan{background-color:#D2B48C;}
.Teal{background-color:#008080;}
.Thistle{background-color:#D8BFD8;}
.Tomato{background-color:#FF6347;}
.Transparent{background-color:none;}
.Turquoise{background-color:#40E0D0;}
.Violet{background-color:#EE82EE;}
.Wheat{background-color:#F5DEB3;}
.White{background-color:#FFFFFF;}
.WhiteSmoke{background-color:#F5F5F5;}
.Yellow{background-color:#FFFF00;}
.YellowGreen{background-color:#9ACD32;}
```

**Code to convert ARGB to HEX**

```
if (!Array.prototype.forEach)
{
  Array.prototype.forEach = function(fun /*, thisp*/)
  {
    var len = this.length;
    if (typeof fun != "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (i in this)
        fun.call(thisp, this[i], i, this);
    }
  };
}


var colors;
colors = new Array; 

colors.push("#FFF0F8FF","#FFFAEBD7","#FF00FFFF","#FF7FFFD4","#FFF0FFFF","#FFF5F5DC","#FFFFE4C4","#FF000000","#FFFFEBCD","#FF0000FF","#FF8A2BE2","#FFA52A2A","#FFDEB887","#FF5F9EA0","#FF7FFF00","#FFD2691E","#FFFF7F50","#FF6495ED","#FFFFF8DC","#FFDC143C","#FF00FFFF","#FF00008B","#FF008B8B","#FFB8860B","#FFA9A9A9","#FF006400","#FFBDB76B","#FF8B008B","#FF556B2F","#FFFF8C00","#FF9932CC","#FF8B0000","#FFE9967A","#FF8FBC8F","#FF483D8B","#FF2F4F4F","#FF00CED1","#FF9400D3","#FFFF1493","#FF00BFFF","#FF696969","#FF1E90FF","#FFB22222","#FFFFFAF0","#FF228B22","#FFFF00FF","#FFDCDCDC","#FFF8F8FF","#FFFFD700","#FFDAA520","#FF808080","#FF008000","#FFADFF2F","#FFF0FFF0","#FFFF69B4","#FFCD5C5C","#FF4B0082","#FFFFFFF0","#FFF0E68C","#FFE6E6FA","#FFFFF0F5","#FF7CFC00","#FFFFFACD","#FFADD8E6","#FFF08080","#FFE0FFFF","#FFFAFAD2","#FFD3D3D3","#FF90EE90","#FFFFB6C1","#FFFFA07A","#FF20B2AA","#FF87CEFA","#FF778899","#FFB0C4DE","#FFFFFFE0","#FF00FF00","#FF32CD32","#FFFAF0E6","#FFFF00FF","#FF800000","#FF66CDAA","#FF0000CD","#FFBA55D3","#FF9370DB","#FF3CB371","#FF7B68EE","#FF00FA9A","#FF48D1CC","#FFC71585","#FF191970","#FFF5FFFA","#FFFFE4E1","#FFFFE4B5","#FFFFDEAD","#FF000080","#FFFDF5E6","#FF808000","#FF6B8E23","#FFFFA500","#FFFF4500","#FFDA70D6","#FFEEE8AA","#FF98FB98","#FFAFEEEE","#FFDB7093","#FFFFEFD5","#FFFFDAB9","#FFCD853F","#FFFFC0CB","#FFDDA0DD","#FFB0E0E6","#FF800080","#FFFF0000","#FFBC8F8F","#FF4169E1","#FF8B4513","#FFFA8072","#FFF4A460","#FF2E8B57","#FFFFF5EE","#FFA0522D","#FFC0C0C0","#FF87CEEB","#FF6A5ACD","#FF708090","#FFFFFAFA","#FF00FF7F","#FF4682B4","#FFD2B48C","#FF008080","#FFD8BFD8","#FFFF6347","","#FF40E0D0","#FFEE82EE","#FFF5DEB3","#FFFFFFFF","#FFF5F5F5","#FFFFFF00","#FF9ACD32")

var newColor = "";

function switchColor(element, index, array) {
   newColor += '#' + element.substring(3) + ','; 
}

colors.forEach(switchColor);
```

Comment: You should do it the other way - post the question AS the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check the below link,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colors.aspx

It contains the ARGB values for all system defined colors.

Comment: That's what I made my conversion off - Browsers don't work with ARGB (some accept RGBA).

Answer (score 0):

As an additional bonus, I also wanted a slightly darker version of each colour to use as a border. I amalgamated a few bits of JS to get what I needed:

Slightly Darker Versions:

> AliceBlue     #d2e1da
>
> AntiqueWhite  #dcb9cd
>
> Aqua  #00e1e1
>
> Aquamarine    #61b6e1
>
> Azure     #d2e1e1
>
> Beige     #d7bed7
>
> Bisque    #e1a6c6
>
> Black     #000000
>
> BlanchedAlmond    #e1afcd
>
> Blue  #00e100
>
> BlueViolet    #6cc40d
>
> Brown     #870c0c
>
> BurlyWood     #c0699a
>
> CadetBlue     #418280
>
> Chartreuse    #6100e1
>
> Chocolate     #b4004b
>
> Coral     #e13261
>
> CornflowerBlue    #46cf77
>
> Cornsilk  #e1beda
>
> Crimson   #be1e00
>
> Cyan  #00e1e1
>
> DarkBlue  #006d00
>
> DarkCyan  #006d6d
>
> DarkGoldenrod     #9a0068
>
> DarkGray  #8b8b8b
>
> DarkGreen     #000046
>
> DarkKhaki     #9f4d99
>
> DarkMagenta   #6d6d00
>
> DarkOliveGreen    #37114d
>
> DarkOrange    #e1006e
>
> DarkOrchid    #7bae14
>
> DarkRed   #6d0000
>
> DarkSalmon    #cb5c78
>
> DarkSeaGreen  #71719e
>
> DarkSlateBlue     #2a6d1f
>
> DarkSlateGray     #113131
>
> DarkTurquoise     #00b3b0
>
> DarkViolet    #76b500
>
> DeepPink  #e17500
>
> DeepSkyBlue   #00e1a1
>
> DimGray   #4b4b4b
>
> DodgerBlue    #00e172
>
> Firebrick     #940404
>
> FloralWhite   #e1d2dc
>
> ForestGreen   #04046d
>
> Fuchsia   #e1e100
>
> Gainsboro     #bebebe
>
> GhostWhite    #dae1da
>
> Gold  #e100b9
>
> Goldenrod     #bc0287
>
> Gray  #626262
>
> Green     #000062
>
> GreenYellow   #8f11e1
>
> Honeydew  #d2d2e1
>
> HotPink   #e1964b
>
> IndianRed     #af3e3e
>
> Indigo    #2d6400
>
> Ivory     #e1d2e1
>
> Khaki     #d26ec8
>
> Lavender  #c8dcc8
>
> LavenderBlush     #e1d7d2
>
> LawnGreen     #5e00de
>
> LemonChiffon  #e1afdc
>
> LightBlue     #8fc8ba
>
> LightCoral    #d26262
>
> LightCyan     #c2e1e1
>
> LightGoldenrodYellow  #dcb4dc
>
> LightGray     #b5b5b5
>
> LightGreen    #7272d0
>
> LightPink     #e1a398
>
> LightSalmon   #e15c82
>
> LightSeaGreen     #028c94
>
> LightSkyBlue  #69dcb0
>
> LightSlateGray    #597b6a
>
> LightSteelBlue    #92c0a6
>
> LightYellow   #e1c2e1
>
> Lime  #0000e1
>
> LimeGreen     #1414af
>
> Linen     #dcc8d2
>
> Magenta   #e1e100
>
> Maroon    #620000
>
> MediumAquamarine  #488caf
>
> MediumBlue    #00af00
>
> MediumOrchid  #9cb537
>
> MediumPurple  #75bd52
>
> MediumSeaGreen    #1e5395
>
> MediumSlateBlue   #5dd04a
>
> MediumSpringGreen     #007cdc
>
> MediumTurquoise   #2aaeb3
>
> MediumVioletRed   #a96700
>
> MidnightBlue  #005200
>
> MintCream     #d7dce1
>
> MistyRose     #e1c3c6
>
> Moccasin  #e197c6
>
> NavajoWhite   #e18fc0
>
> Navy  #006200
>
> OldLace   #dfc8d7
>
> Olive     #620062
>
> OliveDrab     #4d0570
>
> Orange    #e10087
>
> OrangeRed     #e10027
>
> Orchid    #bcb852
>
> PaleGoldenrod     #d08cca
>
> PaleGreen     #7a7add
>
> PaleTurquoise     #91d0d0
>
> PaleVioletRed     #bd7552
>
> PapayaWhip    #e1b7d1
>
> PeachPuff     #e19bbc
>
> Peru  #af2167
>
> Pink  #e1ada2
>
> Plum  #bfbf82
>
> PowderBlue    #92c8c2
>
> Purple    #626200
>
> Red   #e10000
>
> RosyBrown     #9e7171
>
> RoyalBlue     #23c34b
>
> SaddleBrown   #6d0027
>
> Salmon    #dc5462
>
> SandyBrown    #d64286
>
> SeaGreen  #10396d
>
> SeaShell  #e1d0d7
>
> Sienna    #820f34
>
> Silver    #a2a2a2
>
> SkyBlue   #69cdb0
>
> SlateBlue     #4caf3c
>
> SlateGray     #527262
>
> Snow  #e1dcdc
>
> SpringGreen   #0061e1
>
> SteelBlue     #289664
>
> Tan   #b46e96
>
> Teal  #006262
>
> Thistle   #babaa1
>
> Tomato    #e12945
>
> Transparent   #000000
>
> Turquoise     #22b2c2
>
> Violet    #d0d064
>
> Wheat     #d795c0
>
> White     #e1e1e1
>
> WhiteSmoke    #d7d7d7
>
> Yellow    #e100e1
>
> YellowGreen   #7c14af

As a CSS block, using the darker version as a border:

```
.AliceBlue{background-color:#F0F8FF;border:1px solid #d2e1da;}
.AntiqueWhite{background-color:#FAEBD7;border:1px solid #dcb9cd;}
.Aqua{background-color:#00FFFF;border:1px solid #00e1e1;}
.Aquamarine{background-color:#7FFFD4;border:1px solid #61b6e1;}
.Azure{background-color:#F0FFFF;border:1px solid #d2e1e1;}
.Beige{background-color:#F5F5DC;border:1px solid #d7bed7;}
.Bisque{background-color:#FFE4C4;border:1px solid #e1a6c6;}
.Black{background-color:#000000;border:1px solid #000000;}
.BlanchedAlmond{background-color:#FFEBCD;border:1px solid #e1afcd;}
.Blue{background-color:#0000FF;border:1px solid #00e100;}
.BlueViolet{background-color:#8A2BE2;border:1px solid #6cc40d;}
.Brown{background-color:#A52A2A;border:1px solid #870c0c;}
.BurlyWood{background-color:#DEB887;border:1px solid #c0699a;}
.CadetBlue{background-color:#5F9EA0;border:1px solid #418280;}
.Chartreuse{background-color:#7FFF00;border:1px solid #6100e1;}
.Chocolate{background-color:#D2691E;border:1px solid #b4004b;}
.Coral{background-color:#FF7F50;border:1px solid #e13261;}
.CornflowerBlue{background-color:#6495ED;border:1px solid #46cf77;}
.Cornsilk{background-color:#FFF8DC;border:1px solid #e1beda;}
.Crimson{background-color:#DC143C;border:1px solid #be1e00;}
.Cyan{background-color:#00FFFF;border:1px solid #00e1e1;}
.DarkBlue{background-color:#00008B;border:1px solid #006d00;}
.DarkCyan{background-color:#008B8B;border:1px solid #006d6d;}
.DarkGoldenrod{background-color:#B8860B;border:1px solid #9a0068;}
.DarkGray{background-color:#A9A9A9;border:1px solid #8b8b8b;}
.DarkGreen{background-color:#006400;border:1px solid #000046;}
.DarkKhaki{background-color:#BDB76B;border:1px solid #9f4d99;}
.DarkMagenta{background-color:#8B008B;border:1px solid #6d6d00;}
.DarkOliveGreen{background-color:#556B2F;border:1px solid #37114d;}
.DarkOrange{background-color:#FF8C00;border:1px solid #e1006e;}
.DarkOrchid{background-color:#9932CC;border:1px solid #7bae14;}
.DarkRed{background-color:#8B0000;border:1px solid #6d0000;}
.DarkSalmon{background-color:#E9967A;border:1px solid #cb5c78;}
.DarkSeaGreen{background-color:#8FBC8F;border:1px solid #71719e;}
.DarkSlateBlue{background-color:#483D8B;border:1px solid #2a6d1f;}
.DarkSlateGray{background-color:#2F4F4F;border:1px solid #113131;}
.DarkTurquoise{background-color:#00CED1;border:1px solid #00b3b0;}
.DarkViolet{background-color:#9400D3;border:1px solid #76b500;}
.DeepPink{background-color:#FF1493;border:1px solid #e17500;}
.DeepSkyBlue{background-color:#00BFFF;border:1px solid #00e1a1;}
.DimGray{background-color:#696969;border:1px solid #4b4b4b;}
.DodgerBlue{background-color:#1E90FF;border:1px solid #00e172;}
.Firebrick{background-color:#B22222;border:1px solid #940404;}
.FloralWhite{background-color:#FFFAF0;border:1px solid #e1d2dc;}
.ForestGreen{background-color:#228B22;border:1px solid #04046d;}
.Fuchsia{background-color:#FF00FF;border:1px solid #e1e100;}
.Gainsboro{background-color:#DCDCDC;border:1px solid #bebebe;}
.GhostWhite{background-color:#F8F8FF;border:1px solid #dae1da;}
.Gold{background-color:#FFD700;border:1px solid #e100b9;}
.Goldenrod{background-color:#DAA520;border:1px solid #bc0287;}
.Gray{background-color:#808080;border:1px solid #626262;}
.Green{background-color:#008000;border:1px solid #000062;}
.GreenYellow{background-color:#ADFF2F;border:1px solid #8f11e1;}
.Honeydew{background-color:#F0FFF0;border:1px solid #d2d2e1;}
.HotPink{background-color:#FF69B4;border:1px solid #e1964b;}
.IndianRed{background-color:#CD5C5C;border:1px solid #af3e3e;}
.Indigo{background-color:#4B0082;border:1px solid #2d6400;}
.Ivory{background-color:#FFFFF0;border:1px solid #e1d2e1;}
.Khaki{background-color:#F0E68C;border:1px solid #d26ec8;}
.Lavender{background-color:#E6E6FA;border:1px solid #c8dcc8;}
.LavenderBlush{background-color:#FFF0F5;border:1px solid #e1d7d2;}
.LawnGreen{background-color:#7CFC00;border:1px solid #5e00de;}
.LemonChiffon{background-color:#FFFACD;border:1px solid #e1afdc;}
.LightBlue{background-color:#ADD8E6;border:1px solid #8fc8ba;}
.LightCoral{background-color:#F08080;border:1px solid #d26262;}
.LightCyan{background-color:#E0FFFF;border:1px solid #c2e1e1;}
.LightGoldenrodYellow{background-color:#FAFAD2;border:1px solid #dcb4dc;}
.LightGray{background-color:#D3D3D3;border:1px solid #b5b5b5;}
.LightGreen{background-color:#90EE90;border:1px solid #7272d0;}
.LightPink{background-color:#FFB6C1;border:1px solid #e1a398;}
.LightSalmon{background-color:#FFA07A;border:1px solid #e15c82;}
.LightSeaGreen{background-color:#20B2AA;border:1px solid #028c94;}
.LightSkyBlue{background-color:#87CEFA;border:1px solid #69dcb0;}
.LightSlateGray{background-color:#778899;border:1px solid #597b6a;}
.LightSteelBlue{background-color:#B0C4DE;border:1px solid #92c0a6;}
.LightYellow{background-color:#FFFFE0;border:1px solid #e1c2e1;}
.Lime{background-color:#00FF00;border:1px solid #0000e1;}
.LimeGreen{background-color:#32CD32;border:1px solid #1414af;}
.Linen{background-color:#FAF0E6;border:1px solid #dcc8d2;}
.Magenta{background-color:#FF00FF;border:1px solid #e1e100;}
.Maroon{background-color:#800000;border:1px solid #620000;}
.MediumAquamarine{background-color:#66CDAA;border:1px solid #488caf;}
.MediumBlue{background-color:#0000CD;border:1px solid #00af00;}
.MediumOrchid{background-color:#BA55D3;border:1px solid #9cb537;}
.MediumPurple{background-color:#9370DB;border:1px solid #75bd52;}
.MediumSeaGreen{background-color:#3CB371;border:1px solid #1e5395;}
.MediumSlateBlue{background-color:#7B68EE;border:1px solid #5dd04a;}
.MediumSpringGreen{background-color:#00FA9A;border:1px solid #007cdc;}
.MediumTurquoise{background-color:#48D1CC;border:1px solid #2aaeb3;}
.MediumVioletRed{background-color:#C71585;border:1px solid #a96700;}
.MidnightBlue{background-color:#191970;border:1px solid #005200;}
.MintCream{background-color:#F5FFFA;border:1px solid #d7dce1;}
.MistyRose{background-color:#FFE4E1;border:1px solid #e1c3c6;}
.Moccasin{background-color:#FFE4B5;border:1px solid #e197c6;}
.NavajoWhite{background-color:#FFDEAD;border:1px solid #e18fc0;}
.Navy{background-color:#000080;border:1px solid #006200;}
.OldLace{background-color:#FDF5E6;border:1px solid #dfc8d7;}
.Olive{background-color:#808000;border:1px solid #620062;}
.OliveDrab{background-color:#6B8E23;border:1px solid #4d0570;}
.Orange{background-color:#FFA500;border:1px solid #e10087;}
.OrangeRed{background-color:#FF4500;border:1px solid #e10027;}
.Orchid{background-color:#DA70D6;border:1px solid #bcb852;}
.PaleGoldenrod{background-color:#EEE8AA;border:1px solid #d08cca;}
.PaleGreen{background-color:#98FB98;border:1px solid #7a7add;}
.PaleTurquoise{background-color:#AFEEEE;border:1px solid #91d0d0;}
.PaleVioletRed{background-color:#DB7093;border:1px solid #bd7552;}
.PapayaWhip{background-color:#FFEFD5;border:1px solid #e1b7d1;}
.PeachPuff{background-color:#FFDAB9;border:1px solid #e19bbc;}
.Peru{background-color:#CD853F;border:1px solid #af2167;}
.Pink{background-color:#FFC0CB;border:1px solid #e1ada2;}
.Plum{background-color:#DDA0DD;border:1px solid #bfbf82;}
.PowderBlue{background-color:#B0E0E6;border:1px solid #92c8c2;}
.Purple{background-color:#800080;border:1px solid #626200;}
.Red{background-color:#FF0000;border:1px solid #e10000;}
.RosyBrown{background-color:#BC8F8F;border:1px solid #9e7171;}
.RoyalBlue{background-color:#4169E1;border:1px solid #23c34b;}
.SaddleBrown{background-color:#8B4513;border:1px solid #6d0027;}
.Salmon{background-color:#FA8072;border:1px solid #dc5462;}
.SandyBrown{background-color:#F4A460;border:1px solid #d64286;}
.SeaGreen{background-color:#2E8B57;border:1px solid #10396d;}
.SeaShell{background-color:#FFF5EE;border:1px solid #e1d0d7;}
.Sienna{background-color:#A0522D;border:1px solid #820f34;}
.Silver{background-color:#C0C0C0;border:1px solid #a2a2a2;}
.SkyBlue{background-color:#87CEEB;border:1px solid #69cdb0;}
.SlateBlue{background-color:#6A5ACD;border:1px solid #4caf3c;}
.SlateGray{background-color:#708090;border:1px solid #527262;}
.Snow{background-color:#FFFAFA;border:1px solid #e1dcdc;}
.SpringGreen{background-color:#00FF7F;border:1px solid #0061e1;}
.SteelBlue{background-color:#4682B4;border:1px solid #289664;}
.Tan{background-color:#D2B48C;border:1px solid #b46e96;}
.Teal{background-color:#008080;border:1px solid #006262;}
.Thistle{background-color:#D8BFD8;border:1px solid #babaa1;}
.Tomato{background-color:#FF6347;border:1px solid #e12945;}
.Transparent{background-color:none;border:1px solid #000000;}
.Turquoise{background-color:#40E0D0;border:1px solid #22b2c2;}
.Violet{background-color:#EE82EE;border:1px solid #d0d064;}
.Wheat{background-color:#F5DEB3;border:1px solid #d795c0;}
.White{background-color:#FFFFFF;border:1px solid #e1e1e1;}
.WhiteSmoke{background-color:#F5F5F5;border:1px solid #d7d7d7;}
.Yellow{background-color:#FFFF00;border:1px solid #e100e1;}
.YellowGreen{background-color:#9ACD32;border:1px solid #7c14af;}
```

**Script to darken the Colours**

```
if (!Array.prototype.forEach)
{
  Array.prototype.forEach = function(fun /*, thisp*/)
  {
    var len = this.length;
    if (typeof fun != "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (i in this)
        fun.call(thisp, this[i], i, this);
    }
  };
}


var colors;
colors = new Array; 

colors.push("#FFF0F8FF","#FFFAEBD7","#FF00FFFF","#FF7FFFD4","#FFF0FFFF","#FFF5F5DC","#FFFFE4C4","#FF000000","#FFFFEBCD","#FF0000FF","#FF8A2BE2","#FFA52A2A","#FFDEB887","#FF5F9EA0","#FF7FFF00","#FFD2691E","#FFFF7F50","#FF6495ED","#FFFFF8DC","#FFDC143C","#FF00FFFF","#FF00008B","#FF008B8B","#FFB8860B","#FFA9A9A9","#FF006400","#FFBDB76B","#FF8B008B","#FF556B2F","#FFFF8C00","#FF9932CC","#FF8B0000","#FFE9967A","#FF8FBC8F","#FF483D8B","#FF2F4F4F","#FF00CED1","#FF9400D3","#FFFF1493","#FF00BFFF","#FF696969","#FF1E90FF","#FFB22222","#FFFFFAF0","#FF228B22","#FFFF00FF","#FFDCDCDC","#FFF8F8FF","#FFFFD700","#FFDAA520","#FF808080","#FF008000","#FFADFF2F","#FFF0FFF0","#FFFF69B4","#FFCD5C5C","#FF4B0082","#FFFFFFF0","#FFF0E68C","#FFE6E6FA","#FFFFF0F5","#FF7CFC00","#FFFFFACD","#FFADD8E6","#FFF08080","#FFE0FFFF","#FFFAFAD2","#FFD3D3D3","#FF90EE90","#FFFFB6C1","#FFFFA07A","#FF20B2AA","#FF87CEFA","#FF778899","#FFB0C4DE","#FFFFFFE0","#FF00FF00","#FF32CD32","#FFFAF0E6","#FFFF00FF","#FF800000","#FF66CDAA","#FF0000CD","#FFBA55D3","#FF9370DB","#FF3CB371","#FF7B68EE","#FF00FA9A","#FF48D1CC","#FFC71585","#FF191970","#FFF5FFFA","#FFFFE4E1","#FFFFE4B5","#FFFFDEAD","#FF000080","#FFFDF5E6","#FF808000","#FF6B8E23","#FFFFA500","#FFFF4500","#FFDA70D6","#FFEEE8AA","#FF98FB98","#FFAFEEEE","#FFDB7093","#FFFFEFD5","#FFFFDAB9","#FFCD853F","#FFFFC0CB","#FFDDA0DD","#FFB0E0E6","#FF800080","#FFFF0000","#FFBC8F8F","#FF4169E1","#FF8B4513","#FFFA8072","#FFF4A460","#FF2E8B57","#FFFFF5EE","#FFA0522D","#FFC0C0C0","#FF87CEEB","#FF6A5ACD","#FF708090","#FFFFFAFA","#FF00FF7F","#FF4682B4","#FFD2B48C","#FF008080","#FFD8BFD8","#FFFF6347","","#FF40E0D0","#FFEE82EE","#FFF5DEB3","#FFFFFFFF","#FFF5F5F5","#FFFFFF00","#FF9ACD32")


var newColor = "";

function switchColor(element, index, array) {
   newColor += "#" + DarkenLightenColor(element.substring(3),30) + ",";
}


colors.forEach(switchColor);


newColor;



function DarkenLightenColor(col,amt) {
    var usePound = false;
    if ( col[0] == "#" ) {
        col = col.slice(1);
        usePound = true;
    }

    var num = parseInt(col,16);

    var r = (num >> 16) - amt;

    if ( r > 255 ) r = 255;
    else if  (r < 0) r = 0;

    var b = ((num >> 8) & 0x00FF) - amt;

    if ( b > 255 ) b = 255;
    else if  (b < 0) b = 0;

    var g = (num & 0x0000FF) - amt;

    if ( g > 255 ) g = 255;
    else if  ( g < 0 ) g = 0;
var rStr = (r.toString(16).length < 2)?'0'+r.toString(16):r.toString(16);
var gStr = (g.toString(16).length < 2)?'0'+g.toString(16):g.toString(16);
var bStr = (b.toString(16).length < 2)?'0'+b.toString(16):b.toString(16);

return (usePound?"#":"") + rStr + gStr + bStr;
}
```